# Django SQL Server - near "EXEC": syntax error - Error returned when executing Stored Procedured on Dajndo using SQL Server

Tags: python, django, mssql-django

I am getting error return below trying to execute Stored Procedured in Django view using SQL Server database with mssql-django.

Can you help me to find the solution, below I leave the code of the view and the connection to SQL Server.

```
def arquive1(request):

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("EXEC dbo.suspensos")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    finally:
        cursor.close()

        context = {
            'result': result
        }

    return render(request, 'test1.html', context)
```

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': 'XXXXXXXX',
        'USER': 'xxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'xxxxxxxx',
        'PORT': '',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        }
    }
```

ERROR RETURNED:

```
OperationalError at /app
near "EXEC": syntax error
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://xxxxxxxx/app
Django Version: 4.0
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
near "EXEC": syntax error
```

Yes, that's exactly what I want you to help me with